# git push origin master fails

Tags: git, github

I am trying to upload an existing folder into gitHub. 
Following instructions I typed the following in windows:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:myname/myproject.git
```

and then

```
$ git push origin master
```

I get the following error.

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registery. you have no guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is.
THe server;s rsa2 key fingerprint is:
blah blah blah blah
Connection abandoned.
Fatal : the remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

What does this error mean and how do I resolve it?

Comment: No one can help with this overly brief question. I guess you might be on Windows, but I can't tell.

Comment: You'll receive a better answer to this question if you paste the exact error instead of summarising. Even better, include your OS, what you did to set up your environment, and anything at all that might be useful in helping you diagnose.

Comment: Ok... I have added in more details. Thought it will be a common problem to any one new to github

Comment: hi Wesley, there is no way to copy from the command console(opend it from git Extensions). But the error is almost exact without the finger print code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.drewblas.com/2008/06/27/setting-up-git-and-github-on-windows/):

1. Open putty
2. In the Hostname box, type
   **github.com** and click **Open**
3. You’ll
   receive a prompt *The server’s host
   key is not cached in the registry*.
   Click **Yes** then close Putty (don’t
   bother trying to log in
4. Github’s
   host key will now be cached